# .htaccess: how to redirect img,js.. from /www/ to /www/public/?

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect

I have zend framework htaccess now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

But I don't know how to redirect all "link" parameters like js, css, img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my .htaccess which is work perfect:

```
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php     
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$     public/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$     public/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$     public/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php  [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution one**:
Your web server should point to public/ directory, not to root directory of ZF project.

**Solution two** (better one I think):
Your web server points to ZF project directory, or even ZF project is in sub directory.
Like http://localhost/zf-project/ .

.htaccess in zf-project directory (right near public/, application/, library/ ...):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

.htaccess in public/ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And in application/configs/application.ini you set

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/zf-project/"
```

Comment: Zebooka, many thanks!
Unfortunately haven't enough reputation to give some mark:(